# Does "car wash" refer to the location or the action

Tags: meaning

> My friend drove his car through a car wash.

In this case, it's hard, especially if you're a non-native speaker, to know if car wash refers to the action or the place where the action is performed. What do you think about this? I am really confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a location (noun): https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/car%20wash

Think of other terms you could replace "car wash" with in this sentence:

> My friend drove his car through a tunnel.
>
> My friend drove his car through a parking lot.
>
> My friend drove his car through a gas station.

These are all places and therefore nouns. It wouldn't make any sense to have an action (verb) in that part of the sentence. *to wash a car* is certainly an action, but a *car wash* is a place where cars are washed.

Comment: Just to add to this, the verb would be something like "get (my) car **washed**"